# index.html not showing data

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

This is a simple project but I am stock somehow. I am trying to create my own webhooks receiver server that shows received data in index.html at '/' when a webhook is received using '/webhook'. Technically, I just want the flask to show the last data received at '/webhook' using 'index.html' at '/' but it doesn't work.

Here's my flask directory:

```
-server.py
-webhook.py
-/templates/index.html
```

Here's my server.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, abort, json, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    title = request.args.get('title', None)
    jsonfile = request.args.get('jsonfile', None)
    print("Recieved:", title, jsonfile, type(jsonfile)) 
    return render_template('index.html', title=title, jsonfile=jsonfile)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json       
        return redirect(url_for('hello', title='Result', jsonfile=data)), 'success', 200
    else:
        abort(400)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here's my webhook.py:

```
import requests,json

webhook_url = "http://localhost:5000/webhook"

data = {
    'fn_name': 'abc',
    'last_name': 'xyz'
}

r = requests.post(
    webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data),
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        )
```

And here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    {{ jsonfile }}
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this when I send webhook.

> 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2022 12:00:39] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -

and

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

You placed these outside of the function, so it was trying to return all three and didn't know what to do with the "200":

```
return redirect(url_for('hello', title='Result', jsonfile=data)), 'success', 200
```

Not sure if "success" and "200" are valid arguments to the redirect function but the desired result can be achieved with:

```
return redirect(url_for('hello', title='Result', jsonfile=data))
```